# Error: Expected Literal, got '*' in Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

I want to retrieve the number of rows in my courrier table.

In my fixtures, I have these lines :

```
$query = $this->em->createQuery('SELECT count(*) FROM App\Entity\Courrier');
$countCourrier = $query->getResult();
```

I have these mistakes when I do `symfony console doctrine:fixtures:load` :

```
In QueryException.php line 38:
                                                               
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 13: Error: Expected Literal, got '*'  
                                                               

In QueryException.php line 27:
                                        
SELECT count(*) FROM App\Entity\Courrier
```

What's wrong with the * in my query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctrine expects you to use one of the fields of your entity. In SQL you don't need to use `count(*)` to get the amount of rows `count(id)` also works as long as the column is not nullable.

So changing your query to `SELECT count(c.id) FROM App\Entity\Courrier as c` should solve this.